# Chrome 35 : document.createEvent('HtmlEvent') gives error <The provided event type ('HtmlEvent') is invalid>

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

With Chrome 35 , in the devtools Console if try to execute:

```
document.createEvent('HtmlEvents');
```

I get the error as  below:

```
NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'createEvent' on 'Document': The provided event type ('HtmlEvents') is invalid.
```

The same thing works for Firefox.

Comment: That's probably because the Event Constructor is now the preferred way to create events, as in `new CustomEvent('HtmlEvents')`

Comment: Thanks.. but  if i try   document.createEvent('MouseEvents') , that still works fine in chrome(and FF).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit

Try substitute `HtmlEvents` for `HTMLEvents` , all-caps *HTML*

```
document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/Evc5H/

Comment: sorry but is the difference only about  single quote vs double quotes?  Anyways I did give it a try and have the same result. I intend to trigger a 'change' event  and hence used 'HtmlEvents'  , I tried to use  createEvent('Events') for the 'change' but that does not actually trigger the onchange handler , no error is thrown as well though.

Comment: using  HTMLEvents  does not throw the error .  However  somehow  trying to invoke the  'change' event still does not work.